# How to import a large quantity of numerical data

Tags: c, file, import

I'm thinking what is the best technique for importing a large amount of data, whether integer or floating point type, from a file into an array to be processed later.

Considering that the number of data can vary (not all import files are of equal size), therefore in one file there can be 100 numbers, in another file 1 million numbers and they are in ASCII format, I thought that before sizing the array to hold the data i should know how much data will fill it.

I can't size the array upfront if I don't know how much data will go into that array. So I could read the data from the file and as they are read, use the realloc instruction to resize the array every time (in doing so, however, it seems to me to waste system resources since if the file consists of a million numbers, it is forced to resize the array 1 million times).

Or (but I think this would be fine if it were in binary format), understand the file size, know which separator there is between the numbers and then calculate, based on this, the size of the array.

Or again, if the file as I said is in ASCII format, first read the number of separators (for example, they can be spaces or commas), and based on this understand the quantity of elements and size the array accordingly.

I don't know which technique would be the best.

Comment: I suggest to read and process the file line by line or a few related lines. You don't need to resize the allocated memory for every number. You could increase it in bigger chunks, e.g. space for 100 numbers, or double the size whenever you reach the limit. With doubling the size you will reach (a bit above) 1 million in 20 steps. Depending on how you pass the file to your program you could also check the file size and estimate the amount of numbers from this size before reading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of the `realloc` dynamic resizing approach [as Bodo mentioned] from some code I've had lying around. Note the `ary_grow` can be set to whatever you want.

```
// qwklib/ary.c -- quick dynamic array control

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*aryinit_p)(void *);

typedef struct {
    void *ary_base;                     // base address
    int ary_siz;                        // size of elements

    int ary_cnt;                        // current count
    int ary_max;                        // maximum count

    int ary_grow;                       // amount to grow
    aryinit_p ary_init;                 // initialization
} ary_t;
typedef ary_t *ary_p;

// aryinit -- initialize the array
ary_p
aryinit(ary_p ary,int siz,int grow)
{

    memset(ary,0,sizeof(ary_t));

    ary->ary_siz = siz;
    ary->ary_grow = grow;

    return ary;
}

static inline void *
aryloc(ary_p ary,int idx)
{
    void *ptr;

    ptr = ary->ary_base;
    ptr += (ary->ary_siz * idx);

    return ptr;
}

// arypush -- add to dynamic array
void *
arypush(ary_p ary)
{
    aryinit_p init;
    int cnt;
    void *ptr;

    do {
        // got enough space already
        if (ary->ary_cnt < ary->ary_max)
            break;

        if (ary->ary_siz == 0)
            ary->ary_siz = 1;

        // get number of elements to grow by
        if (ary->ary_grow == 0)
            ary->ary_grow = 10;

        // add to allocated space
        ary->ary_max += ary->ary_grow;

        ptr = realloc(ary->ary_base,ary->ary_max * ary->ary_siz);
        ary->ary_base = ptr;

        ptr += ary->ary_cnt;
        cnt = ary->ary_max - ary->ary_cnt;
        memset(ptr,0,ary->ary_siz * cnt);

        init = ary->ary_init;
        if (init == NULL)
            break;

        for (;  cnt > 0;  --cnt, ptr += ary->ary_siz)
            init(ptr);
    } while (0);

    // get pointer to first available slot
    ptr = aryloc(ary,ary->ary_cnt);

    // advance count for next time
    ary->ary_cnt += 1;

    return ptr;
}

// arytrim -- trim allocated array size to in-use size
void
arytrim(ary_p ary)
{
    void *ptr;

    ary->ary_max = ary->ary_cnt;
    ptr = realloc(ary->ary_base,ary->ary_max * ary->ary_siz);
    ary->ary_base = ptr;
}

// aryclean -- free up storage
void
aryclean(ary_p ary)
{

    free(ary->ary_base);
}
```

Note that, for completeness, you may wish to use `size_t` instead of `int` for some variables if your array indexes could overflow a 32 bit number, as well as adding proper error checking for `realloc`

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is not store the data in an array, but rather in a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) storing one piece of data per list node. That way, you could add elements to the linked list at will, without ever having to resize anything. However, this has the following disadvantges:

- Dynamic memory allocation is rather slow.
- Linked lists aren't cached as well as arrays, which is bad for performance.
- It is not very space efficient. For example, on a 64-bit system, pointers are normally 8 bytes long. So, if every node contains a 32-bit `int` as data, you will have 4 bytes of data per node and 8 bytes of overhead from the pointer (16 bytes if the linked list is doubly-linked). This means that more than half of the space is being wasted. In addition, the memory allocator itself likely has a few bytes of internal overhead for every memory allocation, so even more space is wasted.

For this reason, it would be more efficient to allocate an array of several kilobytes of memory at once using `malloc` and, if if it later turns out that you need more memory, you can allocate another array of the same size (or maybe higher size) using `malloc`. These individual arrays could be linked with each other using a linked list, so the number of new arrays you can allocate would only be limited by your available memory.

However, this efficient solution is also more complicated. Therefore, if the disadvantages mentioned above are acceptable to you, then a simple linked list storing one piece of data per list node would probably be the easiest and most flexible solution.

An alternative would be to allocate one single array and expand it as necessary using [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) in large steps of several kilobytes (instead of once for every new element). This would be significantly faster than calling `realloc` once for every new element. However, when compared to the linked list solution, it has the following two disadvantages:

- If there is not enough room to expand the array, the entire array must be copied to a new location with more room. Even if this is handled internally by `realloc` (so you don't have to program it yourself), it can be bad for performance.
- If the memory is too [fragmented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)), the allocator may not be able to find any room anywhere for a large enough array to store all elements.

When deciding whether to use arrays or linked lists, it is also worth taking into consideration that certain operations are better suited for linked lists (such as insert operations), whereas other operations (such as [random access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access)) are better suited for arrays.