# Why should we use a double pointer when we pass a dynamic array as a parameter to a function?

Tags: c, pointers

I am relatively new to programming, and im trying to understand some concepts with pointers. I got it for the most part, and i was looking in dinamic memory allocation, and i understood i need to create a pointer and the malloc function will return the first adress of the allocated space, which we put in the pointer created. That make a lot of sense because thats makes the dinamic vector just like a regular vector, right? Because a static vector also has the name of the vector a pointer to the first element. But why when i try to for example change the size of the vector with realloc in a function i understand i need to use a double pointer as a parameter. Something like this:

```
void function(int **vector){
    *vector=(*int)realloc(*vector, sizeof(int)*n);
}
```

Can someone explain, thanks!

Comment: Because otherwise the caller will not see it when the pointer has changed.

Comment: It means you pass the adress of the vector, e.g. `int *v; function(&v);`

Comment: Something tells me the caller of this function could deobfuscate this considerably by just doing the `realloc` there rather than here. This single-line function seems rather useless, as it literally contributes nothing but code complexity.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The code in the question shows just the essentials needed to understand the question. The other code in the actual function has been removed. Please do not complain when somebody correctly follows the guidelines to provide a minimal example.

Comment: You don't always have to use a _double_ pointer. You can pass a pointer to a `struct` that contains the pointer. That is often more flexible. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60892294/5382650 for an example of an implementation of a dynamic array.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I wasn’t complaining about anything. I was pointing out that if this is indeed all this does the OP may wish to consider throwing it out in favor of reducing complexity and heightening clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function like this

```
void f( T item );
```

where `T` is some type specifier and call it like

```
T object;
f( object );
```

then the function gets a copy of its argument. You can imagine this the following way

```
T object;
f( object );

//....

void f( /* T item */ )
{
    T item = object;
    // ...
}
```

So changes of the copy within the function dos not influence on the original object passed to the function as an argument.

To change the original object you have to pass it by reference. For example

```
void f( T *item )
{
    *item = new_value;
    //...
}

//...

T object;
f( &object );
```

If you have an object of the type `int` that you want to change within a function then just substitute the type specifier `T` for the type `int` and you will get.

```
void f( int *item )
{
    *item = new_value;
    //...
}

//...

int object;
f( &object );
```

If the object has the type `int *` then substitute `T` for `int *` and you will get

```
void f( int **item )
{
    *item = new_value;
    //...
}

//...

int *object;
f( &object );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f( int *x )
{
    *x = 20;
}

void g( int **p )
{
    *p = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
    **p = 30;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );

    f( &x );

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );

    int *px = &x;

    printf( "*px = %d\n", *px );

    g( &px );

    printf( "*px = %d\n", *px );

    free( px );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
x = 10
x = 20
*px = 20
*px = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

When a function declared as `void function(int *vector)` is called, it is passed only the value of an `int *`—just a pointer to the first element of a vector (an array). If this function is called with `function(MyVector)`, then, inside the function, `vector` refers only to the copy of the value that is passed. It does not refer to `MyVector`, and changing `vector` will not change `MyVector`.

When a function declared as `void function(int **vector)` is called, it is passed the value of an `int **`—a pointer to a pointer to the first element of a vector. If this function is called with `function(&MyVector)`, then, inside the function, `vector` refers to the copy of the pointer to the pointer. However, since it is a pointer to a pointer, then `*vector` refers to the pointer to the first element of the array. That is, `*vector` is not just a copy of the pointer, it is the actual pointer, the `MyVector` in the caller.

So, in the first function `vector = realloc(…);` does not change `MyVector` in the caller. In the second function, `*vector = realloc(…);` does change `MyVector` in the caller.